# UI Scroller added around a custom modal automatically by Salesforce on mobile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, modal, salesforce-mobile-app, uiscrollerwrapper

I have a modal that contains a `recordEditForm` in its body.
When I open the modal on mobile, a UIScroller is added by Salesforce automatically. This causes the entire modal to scroll, instead of just it's body when scrolling along y-axis.
I'm sure that there is no UI scroller in the modal component code (not in the markup and not added via JavaScript as well)

[image]

Below is the component markup (Simplified)

```
<aura:component>
    <div aura:id="editDialog" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal slds-modal_small slds-fade-in-open slds-m-bottom_xx-large" >
      Content goes here
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

When I inspect in the DOM, I see that my component is wrapped by a UI scroller.

I want to be able to just scroll the modal body, and not the entire modal.